# How to disable animated favicons?

Tags: firefox, favicon

How to globally disable favicon animation? I don't want to install addons.

example website with animated favicon: http://gimpchat.com/ ([archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170912204735/http://gimpchat.com/) if the website is down)

Comment: @Steven Vascellaro I've rolled back your edit because you don't consider your changes as necessary. As far as I know changing "how to" to "how can I" isn't more correct grammatically and "addon" & "extension" are synonyms.

Comment: "addons" is by no means synonymous with "extensions". The former term includes plugins and themes as well as extensions.

Comment: @kreemoweet: I'm now aware of this, thank you.

Comment: "How to globally disable favicon animation?" wouldn't usually be considered a complete English sentence, AFAIK. That's why Steven changed it to "How can I". Another way would be "Can you tell me how to..." </pedantic>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known concern:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111373

And has not been added as a feature in the 16 years since it was first asked.

You can use extensions and code to remove these:

- http://lifehacker.com/5036881/how-to-block-distracting-animated-favicons

However, as you specific ask for extension-free options, the answer is "**No, you cannot stop animated favicons.**"

Comment: There's a date error.

Comment: My bad. SIXTEEN years ago.

Comment: I don't want to install extensions due to my history with memory leaks, but I'm open to uBlock Origin filters and rules. Adblock Plus blocker referenced in the discussion thread is considered as inferior to UBO.

Comment: The support.mozilla.org link is down, web.archive.org has no backup.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Looks like they removed that article entirely. I've found a similar solution and updated the link.

Comment: "Opened 20 years ago". I love it. These animated blinking icons are so brutally tasteless.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for Greasemonkey solution:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        garant.ru
// @namespace   garant
// @description удаление favicon
// @include     garant.ru/*
// @include     www.garant.ru/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
a=$('link[href="/images/favicon.gif?1"]')
a.attr('href',"/images/favicon-16x16.png")
```

Main idea is to change animated favicon source from animated file to non-animated file.

Comment: The script only works on garant.ru. Use `// @include *`.

Comment: Did you test on http://gimpchat.com/? The website uses file `animated_favicon.gif`.